# Angular list does not populate

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I have a simple HTML list which I would like to populate using Angular, but for some reason it does not work. The `console.log("getUserCollection() Data: ", data);` prints out an array, which is ok, but `console.log("getUser() Data: ", data);` prints out an empty object, which is probably because the list is not populated. How do I fix this?
P.S Should I add the async pipe in the code?

My Users.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AviorBackendService } from '../services/avior-backend.service';
import { UserCollection } from '../models/user-collection.model';
import { User } from '../models/user.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedItem: string;

  users: UserCollection;
  user: User;
  firstname: string;
  selectedUser: User;

  constructor(private aviorBackend: AviorBackendService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.aviorBackend.getUserCollection().subscribe(data => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
      this.users = data['firstname'];
      console.log(this.users);
      console.log("getUserCollection() Data: ", data);
    });
  }

  clickItem(firstname) {
      this.aviorBackend.getUser(firstname).subscribe(data => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
      this.selectedUser = data['user'];
      console.log(this.selectedUser);
      console.log("getUser() Data: ", data);
    });
  }
}
```

My Users.component.html:

```
<div class="list-area">

  <div class="col-lg-12">

    <p class="list-header">Element overview</p>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="filter" class="lb-sm">Filter</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="filter" id="filter">
    </div>

   <select size="20" multiple class="form-control" id="elementlist" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (click)="clickItem(firstname)">
      <!-- maybe add | async pipe -->
    <option *ngFor="let user of users">
        {{user?.lastName}}, {{user?.firstName}}
      </option>
    </select>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="content-area">

  <div class="col-lg-12" *ngIf="selectedUser?.id">

  <p>Element contents {{selectedUser?.id}}</p>

  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstName" class="lb-sm">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="firstName" id="firstName" [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.firstName">
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

---

**Update**
My getUser() method:

```
// Get user
  getUser(firstname: string): Observable<any> {
    const API_URL = `${SERVICE_URL}user/firstname/${firstname}`;
    return this.client.get(API_URL, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      map((res: Response) => {
        return res || {};
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError())
    );
  }
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

My user.model.ts:

```
import { Role } from './role';

// was class and not interface!
export interface User {
    id?: number;
    mandator?: number;
    loginId?: string;
    lastName?: string;
    firstName?: string;
    password?: string;
    eMail?: string;
    group: string;
    role: Role;
    active?: boolean;
    token?: string;
}
```

My user-collection.model.ts:

```
import { User } from './user.model';

export interface UserCollection {

    user: User[];

}
```

Comment: If the data in the clickItem(firstname) method is an empty object, there is some problem with the aviorBackend.getUser() method.

Comment: check your chrome network tab and see if the api call has proper response

Comment: @JoelJoseph the network tab shows the proper response

Comment: @SunnyParekh I've added the getUser() method to the question

Comment: Can you provide a example of what the 'users' array looks like ?

Comment: @Jayme there you go: https://imgur.com/a/f3owVEe

Comment: @Munchkin See my updated answer

Comment: You get an empty array, because the response is `undefined`. You can look at your `getUser()` method at this line `return res || {};`. You should check your request again, you might have an error at some point. Because of that you can't `console.log`, there is simply nothing to log other than this emtpy object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in your `getUserColletion().subscribe()` service call:

```
this.users = data['firstname'];
```

to

```
this.users = data;
```

Also update your `User` interface:

```
export interface User {
    _id: string;
    loginId: string;
    lastname: string;
    firstname: string;
    password: string;
    eMail: string;
    group?: string;
    role?: Role;
    active?: boolean;
    token?: string;
}
```

This change is necessary, because it reflects the backend model which you get as response. Otherwise you can put an extra `map()` to map it to your frontend interface model

And then update your model in the `.html` accordingly to the names like e.g.:

```
{{user.lastname}}, {{user.firstname}}
```

And also update your click handler to `(click)="clickItem(user.firstname)"`:

```
<select size="20" multiple class="form-control" id="elementlist" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem">
      <!-- maybe add | async pipe -->
    <option *ngFor="let user of users" (click)="clickItem(user.firstname)">
        {{user?.lastName}}, {{user?.firstName}}
      </option>
</select>
```

Comment: It shows a comma for every item in the array now. And I also get two errors:`Property 'user' is missing in type 'any[]' but required in type 'UserCollection'.` and `Property 'firstname' does not exist on type 'User'. Did you mean 'firstName'?`

Comment: Could you provide the interface for the `UserCollection`?

Comment: `Property 'user' is missing in type 'User[]' but required in type 'UserCollection'.` :/

Comment: But it works! Now only the getUser() returns undefined

Comment: Ah okay, change the property in your component from `users: UserCollection` to `users: User[];`. This should do the trick

Comment: This throws me this error when I click on it: `ERROR TypeError: "_co.user is undefined"`

Comment: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined` on Chrome

Comment: Updated the post!

Comment: still getting the same error :/ also if I change the `this.users = data;` to `this.users = { users: data };` I get an error as well

Comment: Pardon, that comment overlapped with my edit somehow. Obviously just put it as it was `this.users = data;`

Comment: How do I fix `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined` ?

Comment: Put it into the option tag instead of the select:
`<option *ngFor="let user of users" (click)="clickItem(user.firstname)">`

Comment: it just returns undefined now :/

Comment: A detailed explanation would be nice. On the click or on the service call?

Comment: It happens on a click

Comment: I looked into the network tab and it seems that it requests with the url in the `Lastnamehere, Firstnamehere` format and that appears to be the problem

Comment: Ok sorry, without debugging it is quite hard to figure out what really misses and what is needed, but thanks for marking this answer as solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<select size="20" multiple class="form-control" id="elementlist" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" (click)="clickItem(firstname)">
      <!-- maybe add | async pipe -->
    <option *ngFor="let user of users">
        {{user?.lastName}}, {{user?.firstName}}
      </option>
    </select>
```

I don't think `firstname` is defined when calling `clickItem` on click.

Try to remove the `firstname` param and access `selectedItem` of your component instead.

```
clickItem() {
      this.aviorBackend.getUser(selectedItem).subscribe(data => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
      this.selectedUser = data['user'];
      console.log(this.selectedUser);
      console.log("getUser() Data: ", data);
    });
```

---

**Edit:**

You can checkout a more reactive example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scdzjq
Maybe a new approach like this would help you.

Comment: the list does not populate in the first place.. There is something wrong with my code but I can't tell where it is exactly.

Comment: I added an example for a more reactive approach in my answer. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Hmm this would require me to rewrite the code anew. I will take it as a last resort, even though the code quality is better (async is always superior in my books)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this

this.users = data['firstname'];

with this one

this.users = data;

Comment: `Property 'user' is missing in type 'User[]' but required in type 'UserCollection'.`. It's because I have `import { User } from './user.model';

export interface UserCollection {

    user: User[];

}
` in my user-collection.model.ts

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a name attribute to the select element, example `name="userSelect"`

**UPDATE:**
Based on your example of what the 'users' array looks like. You should be using `firstname` not `firstName`, same with `lastname` and not `lastName`

you should also just say `this.users = data;` where data is a array of the user model

Comment: apparently it did nothing :/

Comment: and removing the click event still does not change anything ?

Comment: removing the click event does nothing as well

Comment: I tried changing it to firstname after seeing the array, but it somewhy still doesn't work